# Limit of integrals, where convergence is uniform only on certain sub-intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Problem:** Suppose $f_n$ and $f$ are bounded integrable functions on $[0, 1]$, and that $f_n \to f$ on $[0, 1]$, where convergence is not-uniform on $[0, 1]$, but is uniform on $[\alpha, 1]$ for all $0<\alpha<1$. Show that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1f_n=\int_0^1f.
$$

If the $f_n$'s were uniformly bounded by $M$, then taking $\alpha<\frac{\epsilon}{2M}$ would give
\begin{align}
\left |\int_0^1f_n-f \right |\leq\int_0^\alpha |f_n-f |+\int_\alpha^1|f_n-f| &\leq \alpha(2M)+\int_\alpha^1|f_n-f| \\&<\epsilon+\int_\alpha^1|f_n-f| \to \epsilon \text{ as } n \to \infty.
\end{align}

However, since we aren't given that the $f_n$'s are uniformly bounded, I'm stuck on how to proceed. Any hints would be appreciated.

[Abbott, exercise 7.4.7]

**Edit:** Counter example in the comments. Abbott should reword this exercise to explicitly state that the functions are uniformly bounded! Thanks.

Comment: Why is $f _n(x) = n$ on $(0, 1/n]$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ else not a counterexample?

Comment: Considering @Keba's example, perhaps $(f_n)$ is supposed to be uniformly bounded to begin with. (In which case, your proof works.)

Comment: @Keba Yes your correct, since $f_n \to 0$, but $\int_0^1f_n=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Keba: Considering the edit, maybe you could turn your comment into an answer, so the question is marked as answered.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Alright. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the hypothesis that the $f_n$ are uniformly bounded, the statement is false, as the example

$$f_n(x) :=
\begin{cases}
n, & x \in (0, \frac1n), \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

shows.

It's good to keep this sequence of functions in mind, quite often it can be used as a counterexample, comparable to the (related) harmonic series which serves as a counterexample for serveral statements regarding infinite series.